# How am I able to check the name of a button in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, title

I have an app, which changes the name of a button. The button on the storyboard has the name, "List 1". I want to check if it shows "List 1" when running the app, and if it does, I change it to "List 2". Please ask any question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please read the documentation of [UIButton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton). There are many APIs in the section *Configuring the Button Title*

Comment: I am still a beginner, and I am not sure what this means. Do you mind explaining?